# Duplicate record after joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I am currently having trouble with my query after joining two tables I am getting duplicated records. What i want to do is get the details from table 1 and the payment record from table 2 with same date.. here is my query.

```
SELECT dbo.tblautoipekonek.ipno,
       dbo.tblautoipekonek.awbno,
       dbo.tblautoipekonek.ipamount,
       dbo.tblautoipekonek.orno,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.username,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.newctfbal,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.addedctfamt,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.oldctfbal,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.newipbal,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.addedipamt,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.oldipbal,
       dbo.tbladdfunds.date,
       dbo.tblautoipekonek.date AS Expr1
FROM   dbo.tblautoipekonek

       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbladdfunds
                    ON dbo.tblautoipekonek.date = dbo.tbladdfunds.date
WHERE  
        ( dbo.tblautoipekonek.date = '06/06/2014' )
```

Comment: Are there multiple records exist in tblAutoIPEkonek for 6/6/14 ? If this is the case, you might get duplicate records since your join is on Date column.

Comment: @SystemOnline yes. both table actually contains multiple data that has a date of '06/06/2014' is there a way to avoid this duplicates?

Comment: This means that you must specify some other join conditions (column)  without which you will always get duplicate records. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @SystemOnline Can't post a complete explanation of my sample data and what i want to see in this comment box because of a limited number of characters. I will post it by answering my own question after the 8 hours as per the time restriction of this site.

Comment: May be you can tell what is your criteria of duplication? I am sure that in your result set, one or more columns might have different values (there can't be two identical rows, otherwise DISTINCT would do the trick). Try to exclude those, if you don't want them in output.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use  "Distinct" keyword at after "select" keyword. it will get the single record.

Good to replace dbo.tablename with alias name give to tablename as

```
select 
      distinct      
      auto.IPNo, ... ---here you can add other column of this table.
      fund.AddedCTFAmt --same thing done here.

FROM         tblAutoIPEkonek auto

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.tblAddfunds  fund
        ON auto.Date = fund.Date   --try to add more join condition so filteration done here of data which is fastest/
    WHERE     (auto.Date = '06/06/2014')
```

Comment: give some sample data to check or give your result.. good to add join condition more if you forgot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.tblautoipekonek.ipno,
   dbo.tblautoipekonek.awbno,
   dbo.tblautoipekonek.ipamount,
   dbo.tblautoipekonek.orno,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.username,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.newctfbal,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.addedctfamt,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.oldctfbal,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.newipbal,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.addedipamt,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.oldipbal,
   dbo.tbladdfunds.date,
   dbo.tblautoipekonek.date AS Expr1
FROM   dbo.tblautoipekonek

   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbladdfunds
                ON dbo.tblautoipekonek.date = dbo.tbladdfunds.date
WHERE  
    ( dbo.tblautoipekonek.date = '06/06/2014' ) 

GROUP BY dbo.tblautoipekonek.ipno,
 dbo.tblautoipekonek.awbno,
 dbo.tblautoipekonek.ipamount,
 dbo.tblautoipekonek.orno,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.username,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.newctfbal,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.addedctfamt,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.oldctfbal,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.newipbal,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.addedipamt,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.oldipbal,
 dbo.tbladdfunds.date,
 dbo.tblautoipekonek.date AS Expr1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you but this is what I would use:

```
SELECT
    p.ipno,
    p.awbno,
    p.ipamount,
    p.orno,
    f.username,
    f.newctfbal,
    f.addedctfamt,
    f.oldctfbal,
    f.newipbal,
    f.addedipamt,
    f.oldipbal,
    f.date,
    p.date Expr1
FROM
    dbo.tblautoipekonek p
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    *
                FROM
                    dbo.tbladdfunds f
                WHERE
                    p.date = f.date
                ORDER BY
                    f.newipbal DESC
            ) f
```

This will get you one line from each entry in dbo.tblautoipekonek joined with the matching date entry from dbo.tbladdfunds which has the highest value in newipbal